# Typescript Generic Object Map

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Need some help finishing off a generic object.map function, my current implementation is both extremely slow on the compiler to the point where it breaks (but works) and currently i can't think of a good way to infer the ReturnType

```
type DeepKeyOf<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? DeepKeyOf<T[K]> | { key: K; value: T[K] } : { key: K; value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];

function objectMap<T extends object, B>(obj: T, mapper: (value: DeepKeyOf<T>) => any): T {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
        return { ...newObj, [key]: mapper(obj[key]) };
    }, {}) as any;
}
```

This will give back a discriminated union of {key, value} object literal pairs such that you can check the key with   key === "foo" and get the typeguarded value of that key back which is what i want.

2 problems.

1. DeepKeyOf often stops compiler working (unperformant) even on very small interfaces
2. Can't infer ReturnType (related to "T" on very end) and 'any' on mapper function

If someone says they can solve the problem with higher-kinded types give me the pseudo code perferably with scala syntax for HKT"s and i can write out a implementation that should finish it off.

EDIT:

```
type DeepKeyOf<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? DeepKeyOf<T[K]> | { key: K; value: T[K] } : { key: K; value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];
interface IPerson {
    name: "susan";
    children: {
        billy: string;
        sally: Date;
    };
}
```

will give back
`{key: "name", value: "susan"} | {key: "children", value: {billy: string, sally: Date} | {key: "billy", value: string} | {key: "sally", value: Date}`

EDIT: This is how far iv'e gotten which is close, but it only works when all keys are handled individually if you remove the "if key == "dob"" the ReturnType comes out as not what i want because Dob is a union of the other types.

// also i went with just making it shallow object.map to make it easier on the compiler and myself.

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
    ? I
    : never;

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type ShallowKeyOf<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] } }[keyof T];

interface IPerson {
    name: "susan";
    children: {
        billy: number;
        sally: Date;
    };
    dob: Date;
}

type GenerateRecord<Tuple extends [any, any]> = Tuple extends infer SELF
    ? SELF extends [infer K, infer V] ? (K extends string ? Record<K, V> : never) : never
    : never;

type ChangeValue<T extends object, Tuple extends [keyof T, any]> = Omit<T, Tuple[0]> extends infer SELF
    ? SELF & UnionToIntersection<GenerateRecord<Tuple>>
    : never;


function objectMap<T extends object, TupleReturn extends [keyof T & string, any]>(
    obj: T,
    mapper: (value: ShallowKeyOf<T>) => TupleReturn
): ChangeValue<T, TupleReturn> {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
        return { ...newObj, [key]: mapper((obj as any)[key]) };
    }, {}) as any;
}

const test = objectMap(("" as any) as IPerson, ({ key, value }) => {
    if (key === "name") {
        return [key, new Date()];
    }
    if (key === "dob") {
        return [key, "NOW STRING"]
    }
    return [key, new Date()];
});
```

Comment: Just curios, why do you need it to be deep, In the implementation of `objectMap` only first level keys will be passed in. Also when you say `RetrunType` do you mean the return type of `objectMap` ?  I don't think you will be able to do any better than type assertions with that.

Comment: Yeah i guess i could make it flat, and yeah forgot to add recursive Object.keys()

Comment: Not clear to me that the current implementation is causing the failed ReturnType inference; for me that tends to be related to the placement of my generics and hoisting R from () => R to be <R>(fun: () => R) helps me.

Comment: Ugh, this `DeepKeyOf<>` definition is poison for the compiler.  It's surprising to me that the compiler doesn't just flag it as circular and refuse to evaluate it.  I'd be inclined to file it as a bug.  Realistically you should pick some maximum but finite tree depth and make your `DeepKeyOf` descend that far and no further.

Comment: It's the [keyof T] on the end that kills it, it's definitely worth filing a bug over might post one tomorrow, i re-wrote it (not with the solution below) with a more performant version @TitianCernicova-Dragomir wrote and gave me on gitter so that part is sorted now, just been thinking of the best way to type the ReturnType now

Comment: I wonder what version @TitianCernicova-Dragomir gave you... if it solves your issue, you or he might want to post it as an answer here.  If it's still circular/recursive I am worried it will have issues, since most circular/recursive type definitions I've seen which have not been officially blessed by language maintainers (and included in their unit/integration tests) tend to explode sooner or later (e.g., when used in a slightly different way than the demo code, or when a language update happens).

Comment: For example, given `inferface Person {name: string, age: number, mother?: Person, father?: Person}`, what do you expect `DeepKeyOf<Person>` to do?  (keep in mind that `{a: string} | {a: string}` does *not* get collapsed to `{a: string}` by the compiler).

Comment: @jcalz this:https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIlKEDSUwHkBmAJKAbaAJwB4AVGKADxCgDsATAZxgHsAjAKygGMQA+GAF4YAb2AwJMANrIYAS1owA1mhaYYpALoAuDTM0VqdJq048QMAPzxEKNFjL6+AH1HK0u5AG4YANwCGeACuULqk+jAAvjC6Iu5gnj4BwaF6yAaRwJFeoJCwCEioGJhkhjQMzOxcvALCBXbFuARQJKR8UipgahqaQA Does not exhibit the same behavior but does the same thing .. not sure why

Comment: @jcalz Recursive type aliases are generally not allowed, but I thought mapping property types (such as this, where you use the type alias on `T[P]`) was a supported use case, or am I mistake? All `Deep*` types use a variation of this as far as I know

Comment: If the recursion is down into a property type, fine... but pulling recursive stuff *out* of a property (by indexing) isn't fine.  Conceptually `type A<T> = A<T>` doesn't change just because you do `type A<T> = {[K in keyof T]: A<T>}[keyof T]`.  You might be hiding the circularity from the compiler, but it's still there, lurking and waiting to spring on you. [I stand by my spineless fear!](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401409120)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I take by breaking apart the object-ey keys and non-object-ey keys. I think its a much wider type space to `extend object`, and it typically gives me a hard time because it includes things like Dates.

```
type NonObject = Date | RegExp | string | number;

type ObjectValuedKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends NonObject ?
  never :
  { o: K }
}[keyof T]['o'];

type NonObjectValuedKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends NonObject ?
  { o: K } :
  never
}[keyof T]['o'];

type NonObjectKeyValues<T> = {
  [K in NonObjectValuedKeys<T>]: {
    key: K;
    value: T[K];
  }
}[NonObjectValuedKeys<T>];

type ObjectKeyValues<T> = {
  [K in ObjectValuedKeys<T>]: MapKeys<T[K]>
}[ObjectValuedKeys<T>];

type MapKeys<T> =
  {
    v: NonObjectKeyValues<T>,
    k: ObjectKeyValues<T>;
  }['v' | 'k'];

interface IPerson {
  name: 'susan';
  children: {
    billy: string;
    sally: Date;
    deeper: {
      norma: RegExp,
    }
  };
}
```

`MapKeys<IPerson>` gives me

```
{
    key: "name";
    value: "susan";
} | {
    key: "billy";
    value: string;
} | {
    key: "sally";
    value: Date;
} | {
    key: "norma";
    value: RegExp;
}
```